# What is the best way to extract the first word from a string in Java?

Tags: java, string

Trying to write a short method so that I can parse a string and extract the first word. I have been looking for the best way to do this.

I assume I would use `str.split(",")`, however I would like to grab just the first first word from a string, and save that in one variable, and and put the rest of the tokens in another variable.

Is there a concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The second parameter of the `split` method is optional, and if specified will split the target string only `N` times.

For example:

```
String mystring = "the quick brown fox";
String arr[] = mystring.split(" ", 2);

String firstWord = arr[0];   //the
String theRest = arr[1];     //quick brown fox
```

Alternatively you could use the `substring` method of [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Split works but is definitely a RegEx based solution which has its own performance penalties.

Comment: Wouldn't it be String arr[] = string.split(" ", 2); in this case since it returns a String array ?

Comment: Nice, but cleaner as just: String firstWord = mystring.split(" ",2)[0]; if you just need the first word.

Comment: This is not strong enough. Suppose the sentence is "Hello, quick brown fox", then the first word you'll get will be "Hello," instead of "Hello". Splitting by space only will not always get you the desired result. String firstWord = mystring.split("[ \\t\\n\\,\\?\\;\\.\\:\\!]")[0]; this will cover more options.

Answer (score 53):

You should be doing this

```
String input = "hello world, this is a line of text";

int i = input.indexOf(' ');
String word = input.substring(0, i);
String rest = input.substring(i);
```

The above is the fastest way of doing this task.

Comment: Make sure you add a check in the event of the string not having any spaces on it.

Answer (score 52):

To simplify the above:

```
text.substring(0, text.indexOf(' '));
```

Here is a ready function:

```
private String getFirstWord(String text) {
  int index = text.indexOf(' ');
  if (index > -1) { // Check if there is more than one word.
    return text.substring(0, index).trim(); // Extract first word.
  } else {
    return text; // Text is the first word itself.
  }
}
```

Comment: what if the string starts with a space?

Comment: There's `trim()` for that.

Comment: flawless answer!

Comment: I wanna upvote this, but then it'll ruin the number 50

Answer (score 19):

The simple one I used to do is

```java
str.contains(" ") ? str.split(" ")[0] : str
```

Where `str` is your string or text bla bla :). So, **if**

1. `str` is having empty value it returns as it is.
2. `str` is having one word, it returns as it is.
3. `str` is multiple words, it extract the first word and return.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: .includes() instead of contains() for Javascript

Answer (score 10):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

...
StringUtils.substringBefore("Grigory Kislin", " ")
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it can be done on one line and doesn't use arrays. It properly handles null values etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `String.split` with a limit of 2.

```
    String s = "Hello World, I'm the rest.";
    String[] result = s.split(" ", 2);
    String first = result[0];
    String rest = result[1];
    System.out.println("First: " + first);
    System.out.println("Rest: " + rest);

    // prints =>
    // First: Hello
    // Rest: World, I'm the rest.
```

- API docs for: [`split`](http://goo.gl/im7OY)

Comment: Split works but is definitely a RegEx based solution which has its own performance penalties.

Answer (score 4):

for those who are searching for kotlin

```
var delimiter = " "  
var mFullname = "Mahendra Rajdhami"  
var greetingName = mFullname.substringBefore(delimiter)
```

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
final String str = "This is a long sentence";
final String[] arr = str.split(" ", 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

`arr[0]` is the first word, `arr[1]` is the rest

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Scanner

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

> The scanner can also use delimiters
>   other than whitespace. This example
>   reads several items in from a string:
>
> ```
>      String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
>      Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");
>      System.out.println(s.nextInt());
>      System.out.println(s.nextInt());
>      System.out.println(s.next());
>      System.out.println(s.next());
>      s.close();
> ```
>
> prints the following output:
>
> ```
>      1
>      2
>      red
>      blue
> ```

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers appears to define what the OP might mean by a "word". As others have already said, a "word boundary" may be a comma, and certainly can't be counted on to be a space, or even "white space" (i.e. also tabs, newlines, etc.)

At the simplest, I'd say the word has to consist of any Unicode letters, and any digits. Even this may not be right: a `String` may not qualify as a word if it contains numbers, or starts with a number.  Furthermore, what about hyphens, or apostrophes, of which there are presumably several variants in the whole of Unicode? All sorts of discussions of this kind and many others will apply not just to English but to all other languages, including non-human language, scientific notation, etc.  It's a big topic.

But a start might be this (NB written in Groovy):

```
String givenString = "one two9 thr0ee four"
// String givenString = "oňňÜÐæne;:tŵo9===tĥr0eè? four!"
// String givenString = "mouse"
// String givenString = "&&^^^%"

String[] substrings = givenString.split( '[^\\p{L}^\\d]+' )

println "substrings |$substrings|"

println "first word |${substrings[0]}|"
```

This works OK for the first, second and third `givenString`s.  For "&&^^^%" it says that the first "word" is a zero-length string, and the second is "^^^". Actually a leading zero-length token is `String.split`'s way of saying "your given String starts not with a token but a delimiter".

NB in regex `\p{L}` means "any Unicode letter".  The parameter of `String.split` is of course what defines the "delimiter pattern"... i.e. a clump of characters which separates tokens.

NB2 Performance issues are irrelevant for a discussion like this, and almost certainly for all contexts.

NB3 My first port of call was Apache Commons' `StringUtils` package. They are likely to have the most effective and best engineered solutions for this sort of thing.  But nothing jumped out... https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html ... although something of use may be lurking there.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: Why the ancient link? Here's the JDK 1.6 version: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found is this:

```
void main() 
  String input = "hello world, this is a line of text";
  
  print(input.split(" ").first);
}
```

Output: hello

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Delimiter is a blank space here:

**Before Java 8:**

```
 private String getFirstWord(String sentence){
     String delimiter = " "; //Blank space is delimiter here
    String[] words = sentence.split(delimiter);
    return words[0];
    }
```

**After Java 8:**

```
private String getFirstWord(String sentence){
    String delimiter = " "; //Blank space is delimiter here
    String firstWord = Arrays.stream(sentence.split(delimiter))
           .findFirst()
           .orElse("No word found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered already, but I have another solution (For those still searching for answers) which can fit on one line:
It uses the split functionality but only gives you the 1st entity.

```
String test = "123_456";
String value = test.split("_")[0];
System.out.println(value);
```

The output will show:

```
123
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String anotherPalindrome = "Niagara. O roar again!"; 
String roar = anotherPalindrome.substring(11, 15);
```

You can also do like these

Comment: This doesn't answer the question .