# Trim a string in java to get first word

Tags: java

I have a String "Magic Word". I need to trim the string to extract "Magic" only.
I am doing the following code.

```
String sentence = "Magic Word";  
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");  

for (String word : words)  
{  
   System.out.println(word);  
}
```

I need only the first word.
Is there any other methods to trim a string to get first word only if `space` occurs?

Comment: String firstWord = sentence.split(" ")[0]; ??

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067942/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-the-first-word-from-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
  String firstWord = "Magic Word";
     if(firstWord.contains(" ")){
        firstWord= firstWord.substring(0, firstWord.indexOf(" ")); 
        System.out.println(firstWord);
     }
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use `String`'s [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method which takes a regular expression as input, to replace everything after the space including the space, if a space does indeed exist, with the empty string:

```
String firstWord = sentence.replaceAll(" .*", "");
```

Answer (score 9):

This should be the easiest way.

```
public String firstWord(String string)
{
return (string+" ").split(" ")[0]; //add " " to string to be sure there is something to split
}
```

Answer (score 6):

modifying previous answer.

```
String firstWord = null;
if(string.contains(" ")){
firstWord= string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" ")); 
}
else{
   firstWord = string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   String input = "This is a line of text";

   int i = input.indexOf(" "); // 4

   String word = input.substring(0, i); // from 0 to 3

   String rest = input.substring(i+1); // after the space to the rest of the line
```

Answer (score 2):

A dirty solution:

```
sentence.replaceFirst("\\s*(\\w+).*", "$1")
```

This has the potential to return the original string if no match, so just add a condition:

```
if (sentence.matches("\\s*(\\w+).*", "$1"))
    output = sentence.replaceFirst("\\s*(\\w+).*", "$1")
```

Or you can use a cleaner solution:

```
String parts[] = sentence.trim().split("\\s+");
if (parts.length > 0)
    output = parts[0];
```

The two solutions above makes assumptions about the first character that is not space in the string is word, which might not be true if the string starts with punctuations.

To take care of that:

```
String parts[] = sentence.trim().replaceAll("[^\\w ]", "").split("\\s+");
if (parts.length > 0)
    output = parts[0];
```

Comment: This answer is untested. Do post a comment if it is somehow wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You May Try This->

```
  String newString = "Magic Word";
  int index = newString.indexOf(" ");
  String firstString = newString.substring(0, index);
  System.out.println("firstString = "+firstString);
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067942/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-the-first-word-from-a-string-in-java#35345069

Answer (score 0):

We should never make simple things more complicated. Programming is about making complicated things simple.

string.split(" ")[0]; //the first word.