# Get First Word from a Text/String Using Java

Tags: java, string

I have an array that contain:

Book http://amazon.com/index.php
Manga http://mangareader.net
Tutorial http://stackoverflow.com

I want to get the first word, so the result that I want is:

Book
Manga
Tutorial

Thank you for the help

Comment: why don't another data structure like hash-map?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5067942/778118) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11607496/778118) (or many others)...

Answer (score 1):

Use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
// assume your array variable is arr
for(String s : arr) {
  String[] words = s.split(" ");
  String firstWord = null;
  if(words.length > 0) firstWord = words[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String w = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(' '));
```

Comment: best answer I've found, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may use the functions [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
       String[] stt= new String[]{"Book http://amazon.com/index.php","Manga http://mangareader.net","Tutorial http://stackoverflow.com"};
       for(int i=0;i<stt.length;i++){

        String sst=stt[i].substring(0, stt[i].indexOf(' '));
        System.out.println(sst);
    }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067942/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-the-first-word-from-a-string-in-java#35345069

Comment: @GKislin for ?                                                                                              .