# Display The String from last having a check on space

Tags: java

I have a String "ZeeshanNisar       192.168.0.1" What i want to get the IP address from this String.i have the concept of displaying the string from last untill there is a space and can get the ip address but can any one help me using code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim a string in java to get first word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607496/trim-a-string-in-java-to-get-first-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.lastIndexOf(' ');` to get the index of the last space, and `String.substring(int beginIndex)` to cut the `String`.

Combining these two is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: "Combining these two is left as an exercise to the reader." best part

Comment: It's sad how even the simplest things seem impossible to many of the people asking questions here. It's all "please write all the code, because I want to be a programmer but I don't want to think at all".

Comment: Why you answer a duplicate question?

Comment: @M.Suurland Well it's not a duplicate of the question you linked.

Comment: @Kayaman True, instead of the first word, the last word however like you said in an earlier comment some thinking of the question asker would be enough to get his answer through the question I linked

Comment: @M.Suurland I don't think I need to justify my actions to you.

Comment: @Kayaman just trying to say that questions like this should be closed, marked as duplicate and not answered since he clearly did not do some research himself. Guess you agree with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
String str = "ZeeshanNisar 192.168.0.1";
String ip = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(ip);
```

This will print:

```
ZeeshanNisar 192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1
```

Btw, this is way cooler:

```
    String PATTERN =  "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

In this way, you can find it anywhere in string, not only after last space, but even if it is before it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression. An ip follows a specific structure. If You Group the String You have Access to the separat Parts.