# Android: How to check String inside of EditText?

Tags: android, if-statement

Example: I have a EditText and 1 Button (onclick: example). I want to check the first word that typed in EditText.

```
public void example (View v) {
    if (edittext.getText().toString() .... //How to check the first word that typed in edittext, 
    ex: if the first word typed in edittext equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
        //Action
}
```

Comment: instead of button click you can use TextWatcher.

Comment: This question has already been asked. You can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067942/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-the-first-word-from-a-string-in-java

Comment: You have to use onTextChanged event http://stackoverflow.com/a/6003815/1584654

Comment: Just trying to find the easiest way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `startsWith()`

```
String toCompare = edittext.getText().toString();

if (toCompare.startsWith("a")) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, all of the answers are working. But this is the best way for me

Answer (score 1):

```
if(edittext.getText().toString().split(" ")[0].equals("YOUR_STRING")) {
//DO THE TASK
}
```

---

***With null/ empty check you can***

```
if (! TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())) {
            if ("LOOKING_STRING".equals(editText.getText().toString().split(" ")[0])) {
                //DO THE TASK HERE
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String arr[] = edittext.getText().toString().split(" ", 2);
String firstWord = arr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this this will help you

```
         String s=edittext.getText().toString().trim().charAt(0)+""

         if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){

       give condition
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = edittext.getText().toString();

if (s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")).equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a faster way for your condition as follows:

```
if (edittext.getText().toString().trim().startsWith("a")) {
      // here your code when it starts with "a"   
} else {
     // here your code when it is not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring method.

```
    String dummy = edittext.getText();

    if(dummy.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
    //your code goes here

    }
```