# Getting first value from a comma separated string

Tags: java

I have a string in the following format"

String s = name1, name2, name3, name4, name5,name6;

What is the best way out to get name1 out of this sing a generic solution which can be applied to a similar comma separated string?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to extract the first word from a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067942/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-the-first-word-from-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 31):

You can use the [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method. It returns an array `String[]`, so you can access to an element by using the syntax `someArray[index]`. Since you want to get the *first* elemnt, you can use `[0]`.

```
String first_word = s.split(",")[0];
```

**Note:**

- Indices in most programming languages start with `0`. So the first elemnt will be in the index `0`. The second in the index `1`. So on.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at [String.split(String regrex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), you will find that it will return an array of strings.

```
name1 = s.split(", ")[0];
```

The `[0]` is the first index in an array, so it will be your name1. `s.split(", ").length` is equal to the size of the array, so if you ever need any index `s.split(", ")[num-1]` where `num` is the number of the index you want starting at one.

Comment: remove space after comma please ,  s.split(",")

Answer (score 2):

```
String first = s.split(",")[0];
```

That should work perfectly fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
 String parts[]=s.split(",");
             String part1=parts[0];
```

Use like this if you want to get the first name

Answer (score 1):

```
s.split(",")[0];
```

Split gives you an array of Strings that are split up by the regex provided in the argument.  You would want to check the length of the output of the split before using it.