# JDBC SQL statement type

Tags: sql, jdbc, metadata

Is there a way to detect `SQL` statement types from query?

Like ;

`"SELECT * FROM TABLE_1"` is type of SELECT

`"UPDATE TABLE_1 SET..."` is type of UPDATE 
...
etc.

Comment: AFAIK, NO there is no such option present.

Comment: At what point you would like to detect sql type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to extract the first word from a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067942/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-the-first-word-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @GordThompson Not a duplicate.  Possibly helpful, but there may be edge cases specific to SQL.

Comment: What would you do with this? It's generally a bad idea to accept arbitrary queries from the Internet. Is there some other use case you have in mind?

Comment: There is no standard mechanism, maybe some JDBC drivers provide extensions to do this.