# How to split an Acronym from it's Meaning in a String

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I want to be able to split a String which contains an Acronym and it's Meaning in to two Strings.

For example:

String main = "BC Before Christ";

//Do Something.

String acronym = "BC";

String meaning = "Before Christ";

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067942/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-the-first-word-from-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split` for this. There is a variant of `split` that takes a second parameter that dictates how many times to split (the size of returned array).

```
String arr[] = main.split(" ", 2);

String acronym = arr[0];
String meaning = arr[1];
```